# Symfony2 & security module: how can i authenticate passing username and password in the URL

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication

I have a configured Symfony2 security module, this is, it can authenticate users from a form that submits to the path specified in "check_path" option located in security.xml

I know is not best practice but id like to authenticate with an alternate url that has the following anatomy: .../alternatelogin/username/password

Inside the alternatelogin controller id like Symfony to make the same check and redirection that would do in the normal submit-login-form authentication method.

My first idea was to make the controller communicate with the "dummy" controller specified in security.xml (the one in the "check_path" option), but using forward or redirectToRoute wont make the trick.

Is there a working way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do your own username and password check in the database, but once you've done that, the following link solves the rest for you:

https://hasin.me/2013/10/27/how-to-login-a-user-programatically-in-symfony2/